# Best alternative way to convert string to DOM element in Angular 7 with Renderer2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using bellow code in my Angualr 7 directive to perform a Bootstrap tooltip to with Renderer2. But Actually i need a simple solution to achieve this solution and make sure that it will working also with Android and iOS browser also.

Current solution:

```
private div = this.renderer.createElement("div");

this.renderer.addClass(this.div, "tooltip");
this.renderer.addClass(this.div, "fade");
this.renderer.addClass(this.div, "bs-tooltip-top");
this.renderer.setStyle(this.div, "bottom", "initial");
this.renderer.setStyle(this.div, "top", "0");
this.renderer.setStyle(this.div, "right", "0");
const arrowDiv = this.renderer.createElement("div");
this.renderer.addClass(arrowDiv, "arrow");
this.renderer.setStyle(arrowDiv, "left", "50%");
this.renderer.setStyle(arrowDiv, "transform", "translateX(-50%)");
const tooltipDiv = this.renderer.createElement("div");
this.renderer.addClass(tooltipDiv, "tooltip-inner");
const text = (this._option.hasOwnProperty('message')) ? this._option.message : "This field is required";
const tooltipText = this.renderer.createText(text);
this.renderer.appendChild(tooltipDiv, tooltipText);
this.renderer.appendChild(this.div, arrowDiv);
this.renderer.appendChild(this.div, tooltipDiv);
this.renderer.insertBefore(this._el.nativeElement.parentNode, this.div, this._el.nativeElement);
```

But i want best solution to convert HTML string to DOM element with short code like:

```
let div = this.renderer.createElement("div");
const message = "This field is required";
const toolTip = `<div class="tooltip fade bs-tooltip-top show" style="bottom: initial; top: 0px; right: 0px;">
                    <div class="arrow" style="left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);"></div>
                    <div class="tooltip-inner">${message}</div>
                </div>`;
// Here i want to convert this string to DOM element
domElement = create dome element from toolTip and then
    this.renderer.appendChild(div, domElement);
```

Comment: `div.innerHtml=sanitize(tooltip)`, where `sanitize` would be a method that uses the dom sanitizer https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: To be hones though, this is a really poor way of using angular. A better approach would be to capsulate that template into a component and somehow "mimic" the tooltip functionality through angular.